# How to remove HTML tags before replacing with new elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, replace

My code:

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/JhbgI

Below is the JavaScript that I use:

```
var items = "<span class=\"brReplace\"></span>",
spans = document.getElementsByTagName( 'br' );

[].slice.call( spans ).forEach(function ( span ) {

    span.innerHTML = items;
});
```

Basically I want to remove the default break elements with a custom span, but with using just purely JavaScript only.

However it turns out that the break elements aren't removed before replacing with my custom span

and hence become like this:

```
<br>
  <span class=\"brReplace\"></span>
</ br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HJkoc

Just change

```
span.innerHTML = items;
```

with

```
span.outerHTML = items;
```

And also change this

```
var items = "<span class=\"brReplace\"></span>"
```

with

```
var items = '<span class="brReplace"></span>'
```

Comment: i tried it, it works but is it possible to make it works in IE8?

Comment: Have you tried the code in ie8? It should work. But if you are trying to test it in codepen it will not work because codepen doesn't work in ie8.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick

```
br = document.getElementsByTagName('br');
for (i = br.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    br[i].parentNode.removeChild(br[i]);
}
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/onmBs

EDIT: To add elements like span add it after it removes the child.

Comment: I tried to add the span to it but somehow it doesn't work and the break tags are coming back instead of span?
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/isDEH